# Xcode default scheme and architecture setting mismatch (iPhone development)

Tags: xcode, architecture, ios-simulator, settings, xcode4.2

I am developing iPhone application and choosing to build iPhone project. However, I don't know which setting or which part I edited in info.plist. Now the default scheme and architecture is set to be Mac application development.

Can anyone tell me how to edit the .plist file or make any setting to make the project build in iPhone/iPad stimulator nor Mac, when I choose to build an iPhone/iPad project. (I had edited the plist file using terminal, so I not sure which part I did wrong and cause this problem).

Because now every iPhone application project cannot be built, even for the new iOS application project (due to the setting will auto set to Mac nor iPhone).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the build settings for your project (and you may have to do this for each target) change `BaseSDK` to `Latest iOS`.

i have no idea why changing the info.plist in one project would affect any new projects you create, tho.

Comment: Erm.... @mike do u have the original copy of SDKSetting.plist??? Because last few day In order to bypass the signature process, I make changes to this file. However I forget to backup, I think this is the causes of the problem.

Comment: sure, you should be able to dl it from my dropbox: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/213246/SDKSettings.plist.zip

Comment: I have modified the sdksetting.plist as the original version.However the problem is still remain the same.When we want to build a project there an option to choose the architecture to build, right?That architecture is tend to be an mac Application development but don't have the option to let me choose to built and debug under iPad/iphone stimulator.

Comment: are you changing `BaseSDK` in the project/target settings? that should be all you need to do.

Comment: the problem resolved. I think is some of the typo in the SDKsetting i direct replace the file with yours. Now i face another problem is: Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 2995.

Comment: I'm followed the online tutorial to bypass the Xcode to signing process....will this error being resolve??? and what will it cause??

Comment: hmm, i'm afraid i can't help you there as i've never tried to bypass code signing